# how to identify what all shared folders from other PCs to my PC

Tags: file-sharing

Many PCs are connected to a LAN. PCs can share folders / data to other PC users.
How to identify what all other PCs (or IP addresses) have shared some folders to my PC?
Is there any way to find out this?
Please help me..

Comment: Are you looking for some programming way or just simple windows file sharing?

Answer (score 0):

If you have windows OS, you can go to "My Network Places", there you will find all the computers that are accessible from your PC.